# Which is the latest version of Xcode to submit app on App Store(Invalid Toolchain error).?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 11.2(11B52) and my app rejected on submitting TestFlight. It says Invalid Toolchain error. What I have found on internet as solution is I need to update my Xcode, but I am confused which version is error safe... I mean which Xcode version should I get to submit my project successfully on TestFlight.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Not had any issues with 11.2.1 (11B53) - Seems that 11.3.1 is the latest

Comment: so, should I update Xcode to 11.2.1 ?? Will it be accepted on App Store??

Comment: Well, I've no issues up till now, but 11.3.1 is the "offical" Xcode version